# mousePressed method is launching prematurely in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I created the following function using p5.js and the mousePressed method is firing immediately when the page loads. It doesn't wait for me to click the button object to display a paragraph containing the ans variable.

What am I doing wrong?

```javascript
function setup() {
    var ans = generate();
    var checkMe = createButton('Check Answer');
    checkMe.mousePressed(createP(ans));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at this line:

```javascript
checkMe.mousePressed(createP(ans));
```

This could be split into two lines:

```javascript
var createPValue = createP(ans);
checkMe.mousePressed(createPValue);
```

In other words, you're calling the `createP()` function, and then passing the value returned (which is probably `undefined`) into the `mousePressed()` function. I'm surprised this doesn't cause an error in the JavaScript console.

Instead, what you want to do is pass a function as a value into the `mousePressed()` function. Since you need to use a parameter, you might do that this way:

```javascript
function callCreateP(){
  createP(ans);
}
checkMe.mousePressed(callCreateP);
```

Notice that `callCreateP` doesn't have parentheses `()` after its name when we pass it into the `mousePressed()` function. That's because we're using it as a value instead of directly calling it.

You could shorten that to this line:

```javascript
checkMe.mousePressed(function(){ createP(ans); });
```

Comment: You're the man, Kevin. It worked like a charm. The additional explanation is awesome as well. I have always struggled with the concept of a callback. But you really made it much clearer. Thanks!!